# How do I output an inverted triangle using for-loop from c?

Tags: c, for-loop

I've created a code to make diamonds by having the values entered.
The output of the upper triangle is good, but I am troubled by the Reverse triangle.
I thought there was a problem with the //reverse triangle, so I changed the `i` conditional expression, but the problem was not solved.
How should I approach making an Reverse triangle?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int n, i, j, k;
    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    //an upper triangle
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (k = 0; k < 1 + i * 2; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
    
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //reverse triangle
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1 + i; j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (k = 0; k < n - i * 2; k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `for(k=0; k<n-i*2; k++){` should be `for(k=0; k<n-(i-1)*2; k++){` or `for(k=0; k<n+2-i*2; k++){` https://onlinegdb.com/-x3Sf9uzv

Answer (score 1):

When you have drawing with loops, first you always must find the dependencies between the input value and the output figure - how many rows generates, how many chars per row (columns) and so on.

In your case, you have "n", and your figure consists of "(n*2)-1" rows. If you have "n=3" your diamond will be "(3*2)-1" rows = 5 rows. Your diamond grows up to row number "n" i.e. if n = 3, bottom of upper triangle (as you call it) will be at row 3.

At the very first row, you have "n-1" spaces on each of the two sides, and 1 star. With every next row the number of spaces decreses with 1 for each side, while the quantity of stars increases with 2 for each row. You may draw the quantity of sapces and stars for a single row, and then modify their values. That continues until row number "n". After drawing row "n" - you must not modify further the quantity of spaces and stars in this direction.

Now comes the second half of the "Diamond" - from row "n+1" all the way up to row "(n*2)-1". It goes backwards - with every next row you have to increase the spaces on each side of the stars with +1, and decrease the quantity of stars with -2 per row. Firs you modify the values, then you draw the symbols.

Here is my approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    int spaces, stars;
    spaces = n-1;
    stars = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= (n*2)-1; i++) //Rows
    {
        if (i <= n)
        {
            for (int a = 1; a <= spaces; a++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for (int b = 1; b <= stars; b++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            for (int c = 1; c <= spaces; c++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");

            if (i < n)
            {
                spaces--, stars+=2;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            spaces++, stars-=2;
            for (int a = 1; a <= spaces; a++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for (int b = 1; b <= stars; b++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            for (int c = 1; c <= spaces; c++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input: 4
Output:

```
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
 ***** 
  ***  
   *
```

Input: 5
Output:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
 ******* 
  *****  
   ***   
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for diamond shape:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int n, i, j, k;
    
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //UPPER TRIANGLE
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int k = i; k <= n; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            printf(" *");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //reverse triangle
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0;  k<= i; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (int j = n-i; j >0;j--)
        {
            printf(" *");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```